# Determine whether number contains different digits

Tags: kotlin

For a given number `n`, determine whether it contains different digits.

For example, 54 and 323 consist of different digits and 111 and 0 are the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although you have received some potential answers to your question, please take the time to read how to ask a good question in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).  What have you tried?  Please include your code and any errors you have received.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```kotlin
fun areDigitsDistinct(n:Int) = "$n".toCharArray().distinct().count() > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fun hasDifferent(number: Int): Boolean {
val stringNumber = number.toString()
if (stringNumber.length == 1) return false
for (char in stringNumber) {
    if (char != stringNumber[0]) return true
}
return false
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't require convertion to `String`, doesn't require processing of all digits:

```kotlin
fun sameDigits(number: Int): Boolean {
    val veryLastDigit = number % 10
    var x = number / 10
    while (x > 0) {
        val lastDigit = x % 10
        if (lastDigit != veryLastDigit) return false
        x /= 10
    }
    return true
}
```

If you need to make it work with negative numbers too, change part before while-loop to this:

```kotlin
    val _number = number.absoluteValue
    val veryLastDigit = _number % 10
    var x = _number / 10
```